# Max no. of Power banks allowed in Carry on - Air China

Tags: india, china, hand-luggage, power, air-china

I have read numerous blog posts advising that we must carry power banks as carry on and not checked in luggage. However, I fail to obtain the maximum amount (number of power banks or capacity of each power bank) I am legally allowed to carry.

I would like to carry 6 of these (2 personal and 4 gifts) - [10000 mAh MI power bank](http://www.mi.com/dianyuan10000/).

I am traveling to Mumbai from Qingdao via Beijing on Air China. Can anyone give details specific to Air China?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my comment was requested as an answer -

I put 6 power banks (3x 10,000 mAH and 3x 5,000 mAH capacity) in my check-in luggage but airport security asked me to remove it and put it on carry-on. I had no hassles whatsoever while carrying all of them in my carry-on luggage. I hope my experience helps other fellow passengers.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to share your experience.  What you are describing (no problem with 6 powerbanks of less than 100Wh) is in line with the rules.

Answer (score 4):

Air China seems to have a [policy](http://www.airchina.com/ae/en/travel_information/general_travelling_inforamtion/baggage_information/restricted.shtml#battery) in place for the batteries (or generally termed power banks)
10000mAh should amount to 36WH or 50Wh depending on whether the batteries are rated 3.6V or 5V. However still, policy says that 2 batteries are allowed that shouldn't exceed 160Wh.

**EDIT:** As identified by @DCTLib below, only two spare batteries are allowed in cabin baggage. So, the 4 additional ones you have will probably be denied when you take them onboard.

Comment: Actually, the page that you linked to states that lithium batteries are only allowed in carry-on bags. So putting them in checked bags as you suggest -is *not* possible.

Comment: @DCTLib - I put 6 power banks (3x 10,000 mAH and 3x 5,000 mAH capacity) in my check-in luggage but airport security asked me to remove it and put it on carry-on. I had no hassles whatsoever while carrying all of them in my carry-on luggage. I hope my experience helps other fellow passengers.

Comment: @AngryPanda Hi, Could I suggest you post your experience as an answer...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius - Done. Thanks for suggesting!

Comment: I know this question is old.  But the answer given as "best" here was wrong then and it's wrong now.  Essentially, as far as security is concerned you can bring as many powerbanks as you want so long as their capacity is 100 Wh or lower.  Up to two power banks between 100 Wh and 160 Wh can be brought on the plane per passenger provided the airline agrees.  This is the rule more or less worldwide, Thailand and China are two countries known for stricter checking.

Source: Personal experience as a frequent flyer, https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/lithium-batteries

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old.  But the answer marked as ["best"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/51119/85480) here was wrong then and it's wrong now.

Essentially, as far as security is concerned you can bring as many powerbanks as you want so long as their capacity is 100 Wh or lower per piece.  Their capacities are not added up.  Furthermore, up to two power banks between 100 Wh and 160 Wh can be brought on the plane per passenger provided the airline agrees.  All Lithium-Batteries have to be carried on board and can not be checked in.  This is the rule more or less worldwide, Thailand and China are two countries known for stricter checking.

Source: Personal experience as a frequent flyer, https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/lithium-batteries